# Path.glob bring <class generator>, not real file path

Tags: python

I applied

```
filepath = Path(file_path).glob('*txt')
```

to get a file under file_path.

After that I wanted to read the file, using the code given below

```
txt_file = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

But, I can not read the .txt file because the filepath brings  not real file's path.

I don't know why did it happen, before, it never happened before.

How to correct my code?
And could you explain a logic behind the Path.glob ?

Comment: `Path.glob` returns a generator object. What did you *expect it to return*? Note, many potential files could match your glob pattern. You have to handle this yourself

Comment: I'm voting to close this, a quick glance at the documentation shows examples of `glob` being used.

Comment: you can convert generators into lists by using `list(<generator>)`. Rather than we explain it to you, you have the documentation on the Path library that you can refer to for questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Path.glob` returns a generator that will iterate zero or more matching files. If you know there is exactly one text file in the directory `file_path` you could

```
filepath = next(Path(file_path).glob('*txt'))
```

This will raise `StopIteration` if there are no files. If there are many txt files, one will be chosen arbitrarily.